# Applying colours other than blue to bin2d

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

How can I apply colours different from the default blues to `geom_bin2d` plots?

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- rnorm(100000)
y <- rnorm(100000)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) 
p <- p + stat_bin2d(bins = 200)
p + scale_colour_gradientn(limits=c(0,50), breaks=c(0,10,20,30,40), colours=rainbow(4))
```

but apparently ggplot2 just adds a second scale to the plot without actually using it. I intended to replace the default-scale...

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `scale_fill_gradientn()`, since `stat_bin2d` has a `fill` aesthetic:

```
p + scale_fill_gradientn(limits=c(0,50), breaks=seq(0, 40, by=10), colours=rainbow(4))
```

[image: scale_fill_gradientn]